# Calling a PowerShell script from Azure batch custom activity using PowerShell and application environment variable

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-data-factory

I've been slowly working out how to call a PowerShell script to transform IIS logs using LogParser 2.2.  I've settled on using Azure Data Factory Batch Service Custom Activity to run the PowerShell script.  I've been able to figure out how to address many of the file path issues that arise in running PowerShell from within Azure Custom Batch Activity, but I can't figure this one out.

Currently I'm just trying to print via Write-Host the environment variable AZ_BATCH_APP_PACKAGE_powershellscripts#1.0 I've been able to print other environment variables, but I believe the #1.0 at the end of this one is causing all my grief.  BTW the 1.0 is the version of the application loaded into the batch framework in Azure.

All of the following attempts have failed:

```
powershell powershell Write-Host "$AZ_BATCH_APP_PACKAGE_powershellscripts#1.0"
powershell Write-Host "$AZ_BATCH_APP_PACKAGE_powershellscripts#1.0"
powershell Write-Host "$env:AZ_BATCH_APP_PACKAGE_powershellscripts#1.0"
powershell powershell Write-Host "$env:AZ_BATCH_APP_PACKAGE_powershellscripts\#1.0"
powershell powershell Write-Host "$env:AZ_BATCH_APP_PACKAGE_powershellscripts/#1.0"
powershell powershell Write-Host "$env:AZ_BATCH_APP_PACKAGE_powershellscripts"
powershell powershell Write-Host "$env:AZ_BATCH_APP_PACKAGE_powershellscripts`#1.0"
powershell powershell Write-Host "$env:AZ_BATCH_APP_PACKAGE_powershellscripts`#1`.0"
powershell powershell Write-Host "$env:AZ_BATCH_APP_PACKAGE_powershellscripts\`#1.0"
powershell powershell Write-Host "$AZ_BATCH_APP_PACKAGE_powershellscripts`#1.0"
```

These works, but are either cmd window or not the variable I want:

```
powershell powershell Write-Host "$env:AZ_BATCH_TASK_DIR"
powershell powershell Write-Host "$env:AZ_BATCH_ACCOUNT_URL"
cmd /c echo %AZ_BATCH_APP_PACKAGE_powershellscripts#1.0%
```

So what is the secret syntax sugar to getting this to work in Azure?

Comment: Nice alliteration :)

Comment: I had to have fun with it otherwise I'd go nuts with all the failed attempts at getting this to work!  Glad someone appreciated my wordsmithing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went through close to 50 tries before getting this to work like so:

```
powershell powershell Write-Host (Get-ChildItem Env:AZ_BATCH_TASK_DIR).Value
powershell powershell Write-Host (Get-ChildItem Env:AZ_BATCH_APP_PACKAGE_powershellscripts#1.0).Value
```

Now this was just a stepping stone to running a PowerShell script stored in an attached application to the Azure Batch module.  I'm hopeful Microsoft will add a Databrick or better way to run a PowerShell script in Azure Data Factory, but until then this is the only method I found to run a powershell script:

```
powershell powershell -command ("(Get-ChildItem Env:AZ_BATCH_APP_PACKAGE_powershellscripts#1.0).Value" + '\Powershell\processWebLogsFromAzure.ps1')
```

This should work for anyone just trying to run from the Batch Task Dir:

```
powershell powershell -command ("$env:AZ_BATCH_TASK_DIR" + '\wd\processWebLogsFromAzure.ps1')
```

Hope it helps someone!

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can do this:

```
powershell powershell Write-Host "$((Get-Variable -Name 'AZ_BATCH_APP_PACKAGE_powershellscripts#1.0').Value)"
```

Or this:

```
powershell powershell Write-Host (Get-Variable -Name "AZ_BATCH_APP_PACKAGE_powershellscripts#1.0").Value
```

Comment: Once again you set me down the right track, but neither of these options worked.