# Powershell can't access runtime environment variables

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-batch

I want to create a task which calls a Powershell script to do some processing. However I can't access Azure Batch runtime environment variables from my Powershell script.

I can access via cmd, command below correctly outputs

> D:\batch\tasks\applications\test12020-05-04-17-32':

```
cmd /c echo %AZ_BATCH_APP_PACKAGE_Test#1%
```

However equivalent Powershell command below shows incorrect output

> %AZ_BATCH_APP_PACKAGE_Test#1%':

```
powershell -Command echo %AZ_BATCH_APP_PACKAGE_Test#1%
```

Of course there is a hacky way around this which is to create a .bat script to call my .ps1 script. But I was looking for a better solution.

Is it possible to access Azure Batch runtime environment variables from Powershell?

Comment: `exho` is not really a PowerShell command, try:`powershell -Command $Env:AZ_BATCH_APP_PACKAGE_Test#1`?

Comment: as `iRon` implied, you are using `%name%` in powershell ... and that will not work for accessing environment variables. you should use `$env:Name` instead.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58631018/calling-a-powershell-script-from-azure-batch-custom-activity-using-powershell-an (see the last bit of the accepted post) has your clue to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

As iRon said, `echo` is not really a PowerShell command, try the code as below:

```
powershell -Command $Env:ComSpec
```

The environment variables in my local is as below:

[image]

And here is the PowerShell running snapshot:

[image]